# Spring Data Neo4j OGM Gradle Dependency Issues

Tags: gradle, neo4j, build.gradle, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to manage my spring dependencies using gradle and the spring dependency management plugin. Currently this brings down version 5.0.3.RELEASE of spring-data-neo4j which according to the pom [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/5.0.x/pom.xml), should bring down version 3.0.3 of the neo4j-ogm, but instead it brings down version 2.1.5. This means that even though I've followed the docs to the letter about [configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/5.0.x#quick-start) that the ConfigurationBuilder symbol is not found. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently using gradle 4.4.1

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

ext {
    springVersion = '5.0.3.RELEASE'
    springDataVersion = 'Kay-SR3'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:${springVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:${springDataVersion}"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-aspects"
    compile group: "org.springframework.data", name: "spring-data-neo4j"

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310'

    testCompile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-test"
    testCompile group: "org.neo4j", name: "neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver", version: "3.1.0"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` with version `1.5.8.RELEASE`. This will pull in the version 4 of SDN and its dependency OGM 2.1.x when you declare the dependency here `compile group: "org.springframework.data", name: "spring-data-neo4j"`.

The only solution at this point is to use Spring Boot 2 RC1. If you would include SDN with its dependencies to Spring Data commons and Spring Framework 5 you will mess up your class path because Spring Boot 1 is based on Spring Framework 4.

Background: Tried it once to integrate SDN 5.x in Spring Boot 1 but it did not work out, you will lose all benefits of Spring Boot since you have to deactivate pretty everything.